# Using a Photogate and a Redboard to calculate the Period of a Pendulum

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ but thought it would be cool to use a SparkFun kit and a Photogate that my school had laying around. I ended up attempting to calculate the period of a pendulum I created using the Photogate. 
I connected a Digital Protoboard to the Redboard then the Photogate. I used this code below I found from the Vernier Photogate Tutorial Page to use in the Arduino IDE. Though this code works it only outputs the time of time when the photogate was blocked.

So in essence I need to track the time it takes the pendulum to first block the photogate, then block again moving to the left, and finally just blocking the gate one last time as it comes back to center. 
So I believe I need a section of code that captures the first time stamp, a section of code that waits until a second blocked event happens, then captures the second time stamp and finally collects the difference? I can't seem to wrap my head around this and I can't even begin to understand how to code it. I was hoping maybe this forum could provide some insight on this project.

```
/* VernierTutorialPhotogate (v2018)
 * This sketch will send a status message to the Serial 
 * Monitor on whether the Photogate is blocked or unblocked.
 * It lists the time that the photogate is blocked in microseconds since the program started running or
 * since the last time the counter overflowed.
 * It will also turn on the LED (pin D13) when the 
 * photogate is blocked.
 * 
 * Plug the Photogate into the Digital 1 port on the 
 * Vernier Arduino Interface Shield or into a Digital Protoboard 
 * Adapter wired to Arduino pins 2, 3, 4, and 5.
 */

int photogatePin = 2; //create global variable for pin assignment to sensor
int LEDpin = 13; //create global variable for pin assignment to LED
int photogateStatus; //create global variable for photogate status: LOW=blocked, HIGH=unblocked
int oldStatus = HIGH;
unsigned long timeus = 0; //Time in us

void setup() 
  {
   Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
    pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println("Vernier Format 2");
    Serial.println("Photogate blocked times taken using Ardunio");
    Serial.print("Time");
    Serial.print("us");
  };// end of setup

void loop ()
{
  photogateStatus = digitalRead(photogatePin);//low when blocked
   if (photogateStatus == LOW)
   { 
    digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);// turn on LED
        if (oldStatus == HIGH)
          {
          timeus = micros();
          Serial.println(timeus);
           }
   }
   else digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);// turn off LED
   oldStatus = photogateStatus;
 } ;// end of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you should use the subtracted number of micros() to calculate period cause micros() contains time starting from program run
pay attention to where you put photogate, if put on middle vertical line, just need to double the time from first block to second block wherever pendulum starts running

Answer (score 0):

Some day I will have to get an an Arduino board to see how it all works. I mostly use the MSP430 which is pure c/c++. I would not tie my processor up in a long loop like this and I'm guessing the same can be said for Arduino.

I would have a main loop that handles events as they happen, like from interrupts.

And yes, you are just trying to get a simple example working so your method is fine. It is just food for thought.

```
for(;;)
{
    if(state & STATE_TRIGGER)
        ; //do something
    //or
    switch( state & STATE_MASK)
    {
        case STATE_EVENT_A:
            //do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Here I assume that 'loop()' is called from some main loop.

```
void loop ()
{
    int cnt - 0;
    int timer;
    for( ; !digitalRead(photogatePin); )//wait for the next low
        ;
    for( ; digitalRead(photogatePin); )//then wait for the next high
        ;

    timer = micros();//here I assume this is a system free running timer.

    //will look for two events as the sensor may not be symmetrically positioned.
    for( ; !digitalRead(photogatePin); )//wait for the next low
        ;
    for( ; digitalRead(photogatePin); )//then wait for the next high
        ;
    for( ; !digitalRead(photogatePin); )//wait for the next low
        ;
    for( ; digitalRead(photogatePin); )//then wait for the next high
        ;

    int accual = micros() - timer; //another assumption as the 'micro()' could have rolled over.
    Serial.println(accual);
}
```

**Update**

How you may eventually want to program this.....

What I would do to make it solid is set a timer up to start on the photo event. And make sure it would do a full count for a longer duration than the pendulum swing. This would happen as a peripheral setup and not be part of the main loop. Shut off the trigger and set an interrupt for the next photo event.

In that interrupt, set a state flag for the main loop, like:

```
state |= STATE_FIRST_HALF;
```

up in that main loop:

```
case STATE_FIRST_HALF:
    state &= ~STATE_FIRST_HALF;
    //and set the timer to stop on the next event.
    //set event to cause an interrupt.
    break;
```

In that second interrupt handler, you would:

```
state |= STATE_DONE;
global_time = timer.get_count()
//or however you get the timer data to global_time
```

Then:

```
case STATE_DONE:
   state &= ~STATE_DONE
   //output global_time to uart
   break;
```